AliasesRequest - how to sort the list in elastic 8 new java client?
How can I sort the list of aliases using AliasesRequest?
this is my old code
Request request = new Request("GET", "/_cat/aliases/" + indexAliasName + "?format=json&s=is_write_index:desc,");

how to sort it by "is_write_index:desc" using new syntax in Java
 AliasesRequest.of(ar -> ar.name(pattern)); 

I need to add the parameter of the sorting to the request.

@Murat K how do you add the sortOption class to AliasesRequest? I tried that but is seems like it doesn't have this option

@murak k thats what I am trying to avoid,, the sorting
